# How does this function "a::b::ptr function(value)" call work in c++?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, scope

I am actually new to c++ and I am trying to figure out how does compiler execute the below line:

```
pcl::ModelCoefficients::Ptr coefficients (new pcl::ModelCoefficients ());
```

I understand that a heap memory of type `pcl::ModelCoefficents()` is created and its pointer is passed to function `coefficients()`. The thing that confuses me is that shouldn't we use an arrow operator like below:

```
pcl::ModelCoefficients::Ptr->coefficients (new pcl::ModelCoefficients ());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement

```
pcl::ModelCoefficients::Ptr coefficients (new pcl::ModelCoefficients ());
```

could be rewritten as

```
pcl::ModelCoefficients::Ptr coefficients = new pcl::ModelCoefficients;
```

I think the second versions shows better what's going on.

In short, the line defines a *variable* named `coefficients` with the type `pcl::ModelCoefficients::Ptr`. Then it initializes `coefficients` with the result of `new pcl::ModelCoefficients`.